# How to delete rows separated by comma?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

Hi I have here a simple question. I can get id from the url of the site and get that id by using `$_GET['']` function in php. My link goes like this: `.php?id=10,11,&from=user`. What I want to know is that if there is a delete sql for the id of the user.

```
if($_POST['action']){
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $from = $_GET['from'];

      if(!empty($id))
      {
            $statement = " <-- SQL STATEMENT --> ";
            $result = mysql_query($statement);

            if($result)
            {header("location:user.php");}
      }
```

**EDIT**
Okay. My table goes like this:

```
ID, Username, Password, Role     Checkbox
1    test       test    Admin       []
2    branch     branch  Manager     []
3    hello      hello   Manager     []
```

I have a checkbox and I get those values using a function in javascript

```
    var id="";
    $("#form1 input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
        id = $(this).data('id')+' '+id;
    });

    $.pgwModal({
            url: 'modaldeleteuser.php?id='+id,
            modalData : {
                id : ''+id
            },
            loading: '<span style="text-align:center">Loading in progress</span>',
            title: 'Delete User',
            close: false

        });
```

And I pass the value in to modaldelete.php through the URL using a script of a modal to pass it to a php variable

```
    <div>
        <?php 
            $id = $_GET['id'];
        ?>

    <form action="submit.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&from=user" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete user(s) <?php echo $_GET['id'];?> from user table?</p>
        <!-- <p id ="demo" class="text-center"></p> -->
        <p class="text-center"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete"/>
       <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-inverse" onclick="$.pgwModal('close');">Cancel</a></p>
    </form>
    </div>
```

So for the submit.php

```
    if($_POST['action']=="delete") {
        if(!empty($_GET['id']))
        {
        $statement = "DELETE FROM user WHERE `Employee_ID` IN (" . implode(", ",$_GET['id']) . ")";
        $result = mysqlparser($statement, $db);
        header("location:user.php?delete=1");   
        }
        else
        {header("location:user.php?delete=2");  }
    }
```

So now. My question again.. How can I delete the id from the URL which is separated by comma?

Comment: Delete SQL to what ? do you store the URLs in your DB ? if yes, what's the name of the table and relevant column? Could there be multiple rows with the same URL ? The information you provide is insufficient.

Comment: You shouldn't use get values for delete requests.

Comment: @Jhecht Then what should be more appropriate?

Comment: The values should be passed via the post request method/variable. It's not impossible to fake a post request, but it's harder and less obvious than having the ids in the URL.

Comment: Did you read the *entire* previous comment or just the first 4 words ?

Comment: @Jhecht The reason why I passed it in the URL is because it is only a confirmation message and it doesn't have any input boxes to hold the value of the variable.

Comment: @alfasin its already in the title and I only put the URL there as an example as to where I do get the variable that I needed for the delete sql

Comment: How does the title answers: "what's the name of the table and relevant column? Could there be multiple rows with the same URL ?" ?

Comment: I can't tell you what to do, just know it's really easy to alter get data. If you're using a confirmation page, have you thought about input type="hidden"?

Comment: @alfasin no need to be cocky. I'm just asking a question.

Comment: @Jhecht Ok. I'll try that. I'll let you know if it works or not.

Comment: Asking 3 times for more information in order to help *you* is being cocky ? good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$from = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['from']); // Protect against SQL injection
$ids = implode(',', array_map('intval', explode(',', $_GET['id'])));

$statement = "DELETE FROM yourtable 
              WHERE from = '$from' AND id IN ($ids)";
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more detailed than that. It would help if the question explained clearly what you're trying to do. Show the structure of your table, some sample data, and which rows should be deleted.

Comment: I have edited my question. please see it to yourself. Thank you for the answer by the way but it doesn't work with my code.